# SSRS Not Printing All Records for Dataset, but Counts Them

Tags: reporting-services, output, ssms

I have an SSRS report (see image) that looks for open discipline reports.  When I run the SSRS Dataset query from SSMS, it outputs 19 records.  When I print it through SSRS it only outputs 17 records, but shows a total count of 19.  In the image below I've shown the report layout, partial SQL (SSMS) results, and the section of the SSRS Report with the two missing records (107 - Gore).  I see that the case numbers for Gore are all NULL, but I'm not calling distinct anywhere that I know of, and the records themselves are not duplicates (different dates).  I'm really puzzled at how SSRS can get the total right, but skip records at the same time.  Printing the report and physically counting the records gives 17 records.  Any ideas?

[image: layout and results]

Comment: Do you have any row groups defined? Or any row visibility expressions? Or filter expressions on the tablix?

Comment: Row Group defined on offender, case number.  I've never used a row group before - I shall remove it.  Much obliged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Original programmer had duplicate case numbers showing, and use a row group to hide them.  I fixed this in the code.  But when the case numbers for different cases were all null, the code was pulling them correctly but the row group was filtering out more than one null.  People, fix things where they're broken, don't patch.